# Not able to retrieve silent access token using reset password flow in iOS

Tags: ios, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am not able to retrieve silent access token using reset password flow. Here is my code-

```
let msalSilentTokenparameters =  MSALSilentTokenParameters(scopes: [MSALAuthManager.scope], account: currentAccounts.first ?? account)
clientApp.acquireTokenSilent(with: msalSilentTokenparameters) { (result, error) in
           guard let result = result else { failure(); return }
           success(result.accessToken)
}
```

Comment: can you provide the scopes you are using?

Comment: and can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm using read scope

Comment: try adding offline_access scope as well, it will give you a refresh token

Comment: I am able to get silent access token when I use sign-in/sign-up flow but am not able to receive the token when I use reset password flow. will the inclusion of offline_access scope resolve my silent token issue for reset password flow?

Comment: can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: MSALErrorDescriptionKey = "User interaction is required";
    MSALOAuthErrorKey = "invalid_grant";
    NSUnderlyingError = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (MSALErrorDomain error -50000.)";
}

Comment: You can find the same error https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1088 , issue is related to response_mode I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what response_mode will do and where should I add in iOS